# Genymotion Black screen virtula device Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion, ubuntu-18.04

I have upgraded to ubuntu 16.04 from 16.04. Whehever i start virtual device it stuck at black screen. Doesn't continue. I have tried solution proposed by other fellows on stackoverflow still no luck.

[image]

Can you help me solving this issue?

Comment: try again by restarting this(close and open agin). It works for me. If it not works, open this device through virtual box. Then start agin it through genymotion

Comment: Not working!
If I run genymotion in the command line i get  "failed to create drawable".
And tail to the device log I get

tail: warning: following standard input indefinitely is ineffective
tail: cannot open '/home/ibnmvungi/.Genymobile/Genymotion/deployed/Custom' for reading: No such file or directory
tail: cannot open 'Phone' for reading: No such file or directory
==> standard input <==